# Urgent Need help to rescue disk

Tags: ddrescue

Please help me to rescue my disk in which I have important data. I have tried with script given below. Nothing has happened.

Please give some suggestions.

Thanks

RB

```
$ sudo ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc2 /root/rescue.log
GNU ddrescue 1.19
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:   318625 MB,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:   24051 kB/s
   ipos:   318625 MB,   errors:       0,    average rate:   72152 kB/s
   opos:   318625 MB, run time:    1.22 h,  successful read:       0 s ago
Finished                                     
rb@rameshbabu:~$ sudo ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc2 /root/rescue.log
[sudo] password for rb:
GNU ddrescue 1.19
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Initial status (read from logfile)
rescued:   318625 MB,  errsize:       0 B,  errors:       0
Current status
rescued:   318625 MB,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:         0 B,   errors:       0,    average rate:        0 B/s
   opos:         0 B, run time:       0 s,  successful read:       0 s ago
Finished
rb@rameshbabu:~$ ls /mnt/data
ls: reading directory '/mnt/data': Input/output error
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the environment setup? Why are you trying to list the contents of `/mnt/data`? Can you share the output for the `mount` command in you question?

Comment: rb@rameshbabu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc2 
rb@rameshbabu:~$ 

{Please note label for sda1 is data and sdc2 is backup}

rb@rameshbabu:~$ ls /mnt/backup/
rb@rameshbabu:~$ 
rb@rameshbabu:~$ ls /mnt/data
ls: reading directory '/mnt/data': Input/output error

Comment: Edit your question. You typed "recuse" at begin of the text, instead of "rescue"